# Why the whole page reloads on reloading the captcha only

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function newcaptcha() {
  var c_currentTime = new Date();
  var c_miliseconds = c_currentTime.getTime();

  document.getElementById('captcha').src = 'captcha.php?' + Math.random();
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <label for="everifyin" class="label">CAPTCHA</label>
  <input id="everifyin" type="text" name="everifysignin" placeholder="Enter the text">
  <button form="form2" onclick="newcaptcha()">Refresh</button>
  <img src="captcha.php" alt="CAPTCHA" id="captcha" align="right" />
</div>
```

on clicking the button of the refresh , whole page reloads instead of that casptcha code only

Comment: **Edit** I have updated function name from `new_captcha` to `newcaptcha`

Comment: What are you trying to do here: `<button form="form2"`?

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that your button submits the form maybe? You can try to prevent default event (which is submitting the form) in your JavaScript:

```
function new_captcha(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('captcha').src = 'captcha.php?'+Math.random();
}
```

Comment: Indeed, wrapping the above html code inside a form tag will make the whole page refresh. Adding an action to the form, like action="javascript:void;"` will prevent this.

Comment: That one will do it also :) Then just be sure that you are submitting the form manually after you ensure that all necessary fields are filled in and validated.